# When the simulator is in landscape mode, the inspector isn't reverted as it had to

Tags: testing, appium, inspector, recorder, appium-ios

I want to use Appium inspector in order to generate my scripts. 
When my app is in portrait mode the appium inspector is working fine. 
But when i want to use in lLandscape mode check the schema i have provided : [image: Photo]

In landscape we have 2 possibilities in our application. In My case the application rotate and the screen is in the same position as i provide in the schema (Landscape 2). 
At that moment the appium recorder is seeing it as if it was in (Landscape 1).
Is there a way to fix the red rectangle as i have mentionned in (Landscape 2).
[image: My Example]

Comment: a doubt : how do you have two different landscape views for the same screen? is there certainly no UI change at all?

Comment: I mean by logic when you make your phone in landscape mode there are 2 possible choices :   
1) All the app is reverted and horizontal menu become vertical. 
2) The app isn't reverted just the screen is becoming bigger.
In my case i'm in landscape 2 all button are staying in the same places menu, ... 
I have talked about the Landscape (1) because when i want to analyse the presence of red rectangle in a false way i found that logic ;)

Comment: sorry I am not able to get you on the point 2.

Comment: Ok, let's forget about landscape (1), let's say that my app in landscape is taking the design schema as i have presented in landscape (2). 
And when i use appium recorder the red rectangle isn't in the right place.

Comment: There could be two possibilities with that, 1st is that the other view is still in background and 2nd is that Appium inspector needs a hierarchy refresh to access the elements.

Comment: No no there is no app in background, add to that there is no relation between the landscape (1) i have drawn and my application, i just talk about it to explain the position of the red rectanlge in appium inspector.

Comment: I am not talking about any other app, but the 'view' displayed as shown in the image. 
What I meant was that probably your Portrait mode view is still there in the background even on launching to Landscape view(another view drawn)

Comment: My application is displayed as the picture landscape (2).

Comment: All the images attached looks similar due to editing, and it cannot be inferred if there is anything different in any of them (different app, different menu, different view etc)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112123/discussion-between-emna-and-nullpointer).